# Drag and Drop Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, drag-and-drop

I have made a drag-and-drop feature so that users can drag an icon from the sidebar and when they ***drop*** the icon, a marker is placed.

The below implementation seemed like the best (only) way to achieve it, but issues are occurring when the network is slow, presumably because the lat/lng from the mouseover event is (very) inaccurate.

Can anyone offer an alternative way I could do this? Perhaps placing the marker immediately and then using the built-in maps drag-n-drop ?

```js
function placeMarker(lat, lng) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  return marker;
}

$(".icon").draggable({helper: 'clone',

  start: function(e, ui) {
    map.setOptions({draggable: false});
    $("#map").css('cursor', 'crosshair');
  },

  stop: function(e,ui) {
    map.setOptions({draggable: true});
    $("#map").css('cursor', 'default');

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "mouseover", function(event) {
      var lat = event.latLng.lat(),
          lng = event.latLng.lng(),
          id = ui.helper.context.id;

      pointA = id === "pointA" && pointA === true 
                       ? pointA.setMap(null) : placeMarker(lat, lng); 

      pointB = id === "pointB" && pointB === true 
                       ? pointB.setMap(null) : placeMarker(lat, lng);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What are the *issues* that are occurring?

Comment: The marker takes long to place and when it does, it is being placed in the wrong location on the map.

Comment: maybe try use the `google.maps.Geocoder() ` service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved when using the `mousemove` event instead of `mouseover`.

I think this is the event I should have been using all along. The low latency obviously interferes with the initial `mouseover` event not firing as the pin is dropped.

Hope this can help others.